# MEF container hierarchy and GetExports<T>

Tags: c#, mef, containers, hierarchy

I am using container hierarchy to control IDisposable parts lifetime. Child container is attached to the filtered catalog that contains non-shared parts. Here is a code snippet:

```
[Export(typeof(ITest)), PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
class Test : ITest, IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose() {}
}

public interface ITest {}

class Program
{
  static void Main()
  {
    // parent container to hold shared disposable parts
    var cat = new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(Program).Assembly);
    var parent = new CompositionContainer(cat);

    // child container to hold non-shared disposable parts
    var nsCat = CreateNonSharedPartCatalog(cat);
    var child = new CompositionContainer(nsCat, parent);

    // no cardinality mismatch exception: exactly one export found
    var exp = child.GetExport<ITest>();

    // lazy exports: count == 2 -- why?
    var exports = child.GetExports<ITest>();
    Console.WriteLine("Exports count = {0}", exports.Count());
  }

  static ComposablePartCatalog 
    CreateNonSharedPartCatalog(ComposablePartCatalog cat)
  {
    return new FilteredCatalog(cat,
      def => def.Metadata.ContainsKey(
        CompositionConstants.PartCreationPolicyMetadataName) &&
      ((CreationPolicy)def.Metadata[
        CompositionConstants.PartCreationPolicyMetadataName]) == 
          CreationPolicy.NonShared);
  }
}
```

(FilteredCatalog class is the same that mentioned in MEF documentation).

GetExport doesn't throw cardinality mismatch exception which indicates that there is no ambiguity (exactly one export is found). But to my surprise, GetExports() returns 2 lazy exports instead of 1.

I this a bug or this behavior is by design? How could I set up child container so that GetExports returns one export in this sample?

Comment: is anything importing `ITest`?

Comment: No, I've posted the complete snippet here. Only usings and FilteredCatalog class code is removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is a known limitation of container hierarchies in MEF using filtered catalogs.  I believe (but can't confirm right now) that setting the import source:

```
[ImportMany(Source=ImportSource.Local)]
public IEnumerable<ITest> Tests { get; set; }
```

Should give the behaviour you want (but only in MEF2/.NET 4.5 Developer Preview).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Is this feature available in MEF2 Preview5 published at CodePlex?

Comment: This feature works as described, and is indeed available in MEF2 Preview5 published at CodePlex. However, setting Source to ImportSource.Local will pull parts from the child container only, so non-shared parts couldn't be imported this way. What I was trying to do is to get all exported parts (both shared and non-shared), but without duplicates.

Comment: Ah - I see the issue, sorry. Also in 4.5 DP we have `CompositionScopeDefinition` which has a better chance of handling this case - see: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2011/12/19/sharing-with-compositionscopedefinition-in-mef2-alok.aspx

Comment: One more thing: ImportSource parameter is ignored for export factories. Looks like a bug.